# Split Column and then aggregate count of unique values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
  color  type
1 black chair
2 black chair
3 black  sofa
4 green table
5 green  sofa
```

I want to split this to form the following dataset:

```
    arg value
1 color black
2 color black
3 color black
4 color green
5 color green
6  type chair
7  type chair
8  type  sofa
9  type table
10 type  sofa
```

I would then like to calculate unique values of all arg-value combination:

```
    arg value count
1 color black     3
2 color green     2
3  type chair     2
4  type  sofa     2
5  type table     1
```

It does not need to be sorted by count. This would then be printed in the following output form:

```
    arg unique_count_values
1 color black(3) green(2)
2  type chair(2) sofa(2) table(1)
```

I tried the following:

```
AttrList<-colnames(DataSet)
aggregate(.~ AttrList, DataSet, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)) )
```

I also tried `summary(DataSet)` but then I am not sure how to manipulate the result to get it in the desired Output form.

I am relatively new to R. If you find something that would reduce the effort then please let me know. Thanks!

**Update**

So, I tried the following:

```
x <- matrix(c(101:104,101:104,105:106,1,2,3,3,4,5,4,5,7,5), nrow=10, ncol=2) 

     V1   V2
 1  101    1
 2  102    2
 3  103    3
 4  104    3
 5  101    4
 6  102    5
 7  103    4
 8  104    5
 9  105    7
10  106    5
```

Converting to `table`:

```
as.data.frame(table(x))
```

Which gives me:

```
     x Freq
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    2
4    4    2
5    5    3
6    7    1
7  101    2
8  102    2
9  103    2
10 104    2
11 105    1
12 106    1
```

What should I do so I get this:

```
    V Val Freq
1  V2   1    1
2  V2   2    1
3  V2   3    2
4  V2   4    2
5  V2   5    3
6  V2   7    1
7  V1 101    2
8  V1 102    2
9  V1 103    2
10 V1 104    2
11 V1 105    1
12 V1 106    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  gather(arg, value) %>%
  count(arg, value) %>%
  summarise(unique_count_values = toString(paste0(value, "(", n, ")")))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#     arg         unique_count_values
#  (fctr)                       (chr)
#1  color          black(3), green(2)
#2   type chair(2), sofa(2), table(1)
```

Comment: Can this be achieved using FNN, plyr or a base package ?

Comment: I wanted to know any alternative methods cos this seems a little complex for me to understand.

Comment: Also, I still want to know how to convert my dataset to obtain arg and value columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R approach. I've expanded it out a bit mostly so that I can add comments as to what is happening.

The basic idea is to just use `sapply` to loop through the columns, tabulate the data in each column, and then use `sprintf` to extract the relevant parts of the tabulation to achieve your desired output (the names, followed by the values in brackets).

The `stack` function takes the final named vector and converts it to a `data.frame`.

```
stack(                        ## convert the final output to a data.frame
  sapply(                     ## cycle through each column
    mydf, function(x) {
      temp <- table(x)        ## calculate counts and paste together values
      paste(sprintf("%s (%d)", names(temp), temp), collapse = " ")
    }))
#                         values   ind
# 1          black (3) green (2) color
# 2 chair (2) sofa (2) table (1)  type
```

---

If the data are `factor`s, you could also try something like the following, which matches the data you expect, but not the desired output.

```
stack(apply(summary(mydf), 2, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = " ")))
#                          values     ind
# 1           black:3   green:2     color
# 2 chair:2   sofa :2   table:1      type
```